# Tab complete global alias names not at the beginning of a line

Tags: zsh, alias, autocomplete

I have a bunch of aliases like this

```
alias -g foo=cmd1
alias -g faz=cmd2
alias -g fam=cmd3
```

At the shell (I'm using zsh) I want to be able to type

```
echo fa<TAB>
```

and be prompted for `faz` or `fam`

[complete_aliases](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html) option doesn't seem right (and didn't work) and compdef is for completion for `cmd*` not to complete the alias name itself.

If I use the aliases at the beginning of a line they **do** offer tab completion. It's only when it's used somewhere else in the line.

Functions like oh-my-zsh's [globalias](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/globalias/globalias.plugin.zsh) works for expanding the alias after I type the full name and push space but I'm looking for something that will expand the alias if I don't remember the full name of it.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `~/.zshrc` file:

```bsh
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
# The code below should come _after_ initializing the completion system.

# Autoload the `galiases` table.
zmodload -Fa zsh/parameter p:galiases

# Whenever a completion is attempted, first run `_galiases`.
compdef _galiases -first-

_galiases() {
  # Add the completions to the `aliases` group.
  local expl
  _description aliases expl 'alias'

  # Add the keys from `galiases` as the actual completions.
  compadd "$expl[@]" -Q -k galiases
}
```

(Note that you cannot define multiple completion functions as `-first-`. If you have other completion functions that should be called first, then you should define an umbrella function that calls all of them.)

Documentation:

- [`zsh/parameter`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fparameter-Module)
- [`galiases`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-galiases)
- [`_description`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fdescription)
  galiases)
- [`compadd`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-Widgets.html#index-compadd)

Comment: You should put the `zmodload` line outside the function. It only needs to be called once.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my answer.